# GraphQL playground type detail multiline comment?

Tags: graphql, graphql-playground

I am trying to document my APIs using GraphQL. For readability issues, I want to leave comments in multi-line but it doesn't seem to work with regular '\n' newline symbol

```
"""
  Return:\n true : DB save successful\n false : DB save unsuccessful
"""
```

This is what i tried

However it outputs exactly the same without putting lines in the new line

```
Return:\n true : DB save successful\n false : DB save unsuccessful
```

Is it possible to arrange texts in new line like:

```
Return:
 true : DB save successful
 false : DB save unsuccessful
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Block strings don't allow escaping characters by design, but you can just utilize new lines inside the string:

```
"""
Return:
true : DB save successful
false : DB save unsuccessful
"""
```

Or you can utilize a regular string, which allows escaped characters:

```
"Return:\n true : DB save successful\n false : DB save unsuccessful"
```

EDIT:

GraphQL Playground uses [this component](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/blob/55d6946a1fdad2fa0276e5c33ca3534cc5a63c67/packages/graphiql/src/components/DocExplorer/MarkdownContent.js) under the hood to render the descriptions, which itself treats the description as markdown and renders it using [markdown-it](https://markdown-it.github.io/). Markdown ignores single line breaks, so you would have to use two:

```
"""
Return:

true : DB save successful

false : DB save unsuccessful
"""
```

Comment: Both don't seem to work for me... prints everything in one line in graphql playground

Comment: Are you referring to the DOCS tab in Playground?

Comment: yes. I'm writing comments in schema.graphql and viewing it in playground > docs

Comment: Done. didn't know about that.  Thanks!